# slidetoggle reset state on AJAX Post

Tags: jquery, ajax, slidetoggle

I've run into a bit of a problem that I'm hoping you can help me with. I've got a form that opens with slidetoggle(); Works like a charm. The form inside that element #dialog the performs an AJAX Post submit. All works to perfection.

Here's the problem: When the form is submitted, slidetoggle seems to lose its state, and when the user then subsequently clicks the button that fires the slidetoggle, nothing happens. If I refresh the main page in my success function, then everything works as expected - however that seems to defeat the purpose of an AJAX Post submit in the first place. Here's my code:

```
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "{U_NEW}",
                data: dataString,
                success: function()
                    {
                        $('#reply-dialog').html("<div id='succes'></div>");
                        $('#succes').html("<h2>{L_DRAFT_SAVED}</h2>")
                        .hide()
                        .fadeIn(800, function()
                            {
                            $('#succes')
                        });

                        $('#succes').delay(2000).slideUp(500, function()
                            {
                                    location.reload();
                                    parent.conversations.location='{U_CONVERSATIONS}';
                            });
                    }
            });
```

The code that fires the slidetoggle:

```
$(function()
{
        $("#new").click(function ()
        {
                $("#dialog").slideToggle("100");
        });
});
```

And the #dialog div

```
        <div id="dialog">
          <div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="padding: .7em;">
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <form action="">
                      <fieldset style="border: none;">
                        <h2>{L_NEW_MESSAGE}</h2>
                        <label for="recipient" id="recipient_label">{L_RECIPIENT}: <span class="small-font">{L_RECIPIENT_EXPLAIN}</span></label></label>
                        <br />
                        <input type="text" name="recipient" id="recipient" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label class="error" for="recipient" id="recipient_error">{L_FIELD_REQUIRED}</label>
                        <label class="error" for="recipient" id="recipient_name_error">{L_RECIPIENT_NOT_FOUND}</label>
                            <br />
                        <label for="subject" id="subject_label">{L_SUBJECT}:</label>
                        <br />
                        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label class="error" for="subject" id="subject_error">{L_FIELD_REQUIRED}</label>
                            <br />
                        <label for="message" id="message_label">{L_MESSAGE}:</label>
                        <br />
                        <textarea name="message" style="width: 99%;" rows="10" id="message" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></textarea>
                        <label class="error" for="message" id="message_error">{L_FIELD_REQUIRED}</label>

                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="{L_SEND_MESSAGE}" />
            <input type="submit" name="draft" id="draft" value="{L_SAVE_AS_A_DRAFT}" />

                      </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use live(), delegate() or on() depending on your version of JQuery (older to newer) for binding to DOM objects loaded from your AJAX call

e.g. $(document).on("#new","click", function ()

Read more here:
http://api.jquery.com/on/